# Where is form_load event in JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I have a project which have two form. 1st is `JFrame` and 2nd is `JInternalFrame`. I make a 1st one like MDI form. When I click on menu of 1st form, The 2nd form should be showed and contain a lot of data from Ms. Access 2003 Database. I fail to add event to the 2nd form, Where is form load in JInternalFrame. I try the implement my 2nd form with `WindowListener`, but it is not work. Please help !

Answer (score 1):

From waht I understand, you have a [`JFrame`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) that may contain [`JInternalFrame`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) and you want a menu item to create a JInternalFrame, isn't it ?

if so, the answer is as simple as a look to the Swing tutorial : [How to use menus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). what you'll have to do is is to create either an Action or an [`ActionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) which [`actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29) method will create the new JInternalFrame and make it visible in your [`JDesktopPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html).